# Is there a way in Json Schema to compare two strings

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Consider the below json structure. Now I want to compare internal subDomain value with internet-facing subDomain value and viceversa.
If both are same fail the validation. Is this possible with JsonSchema? If yes can I get sample code.

```
"internal": {
  "domain":"test.com"
  "subDomain": "api"
}

"internet-facing": {
  "domain":"test.com"
  "subDomain": "api"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not possible with JSON Schema. Some implementations add their own keywords which can access instance data, but this makes your schema non-interoperable.